# MySQL query selecting values from two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have the following two tables:

```
Cities: id | name | county_id
Counties: id | name
```

I am passing this query a county 'name' and I am trying to select id and name of all rows from cities with the same county_id. I am having difficulty building a query across these two database tables. Here is what I have:

```
"SELECT cities.id,cities.name
FROM cities,counties
WHERE counties.name='$county' AND cities.county_id=counties.id
ORDER BY cities.name ASC";
```

Comment: How does the above fail?  It looks fine to me.

Comment: I'm sorry guys, it was actually an error in my database which wasn't producing any results. The above does actually work

Answer (score 2):

If you're running on Unix and if I take your question *literally*, your problem may be with case-sensitivity.

Table names are case-sensitive in Unix, so if your tables are called `Counties` and `Cities`, then you have a problem when you use `counties` and `cities` in your SQL query.

That said, Will A's response regarding `mysql_error()` is crucial... have your code print out the error and post it here if you need further assistance.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT cities.id,cities.name
FROM Counties INNER JOIN CITIES 
ON Counties.id = Cities.county_id
WHERE  counties.name='$county'
ORDER BY cities.name ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you're using mysql_query("..."), so drop an `echo mysql_error();` line immediately below the query and see whether it's failing for some reason.  I reckon you've not connected properly in this case, and the original query looks fine (albeit using the old join syntax - better syntax given below)...

```
SELECT ci.id, ci.name
FROM  cities ci
INNER JOIN counties co
ON ci.county_id = co.id
WHERE co.name='$county'
ORDER BY ci.name ASC
```